# How to install VMware on 12.10?

Tags: software-installation, 12.10, vmware

When installing VMware, it doesn't let you do it all through Ubuntu Software Centre; you get a .bundle file, and have to run that first to install the program, then once installed it says that it cannot find something to do with the kernel like it has done in previous versions. I tried using the shell scripts for older versions to patch it, but it doesn't work, and yes I did edit the file to work with VMware 5.0.0 but it still didn't work, I kept messing around with it until it did work.. but gave me a a black screen with loads of writing about my PC and VMware etc. not allowing me to do anything apart from moving the mouse...

I reinstalled the OS, and want to make sure I install it correctly this time, someone please explain how I do it, thanks!

Comment: What VMware product are you referring to? VMware Player, VMware Server, VMware Workstation, etc. And do you really need VMware to run virtual machines? On Linux you have more options which are better integrated in Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were experiencing the problems VMWare 9.0.0 had with the new 3.5 Kernel in ubuntu 12.10

Since 9.0.1 is now available download and install that.

If anyone else gets into the situation Lewis did, you do not need to reinstall your OS.

reboot in single user mode by pressing e at the grub loader and adding `single` at the end of the kernel line. Then press F10

You should get a root prompt where you can run the uninstall command:

```
vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-workstation
```